# google bookmarks not visible in https://www.google.com.au/bookmarks/

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have been using Xmarks for a long time to sync my bookmarks. But for some reason, I want to use google bookmark sync feature.
I followed the following steps but was unable to view my bookmarks at:- 
https://www.google.com.au/bookmarks/

Steps:-
**Step 1**: Open the hamburger menu in your Chrome browser (the three lines in the upper right-hand corner) and choose Settings.

Start sync setup

**Step 2**: In the new tab that opens, click the Sign in to Chrome button near the top and sign-in to your account.

Choose the features you want to sync.

**Step 3**: You can choose which settings you want to sync or "Sync everything."

After all these steps I cannot find my bookmarks at:- 
https://www.google.com.au/bookmarks/

Am I missing some steps OR does the bookmarks does not appear here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Google Bookmarks is a free online bookmarking service, available to Google Account holders. It is completely separate from browser-based bookmarking and should not be confused with the Bookmarks function on any popular browser, Google Chrome included.

([Src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Bookmarks))

Also check out: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53099/google-chrome-bookmarks-or-google-bookmarks